# How do I bring ED-E to the scrapyard?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have the quest "ED-E My Love". However, I cannot just pick him up and walk outside (he's in a house). Is it possible to do that quest when I don't have the science/repair to fix him first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You'll need to get Ed-E fixed up first. If you lack the requisite Science or Repair skills, you should be able to substitute a lot of parts for any actual knowledge. Specifically, 3 Scrap Metal, 2 Sensor Modules, and one Scrap Electronics.

Alternately, you can just come back later, or pop a Skill Magazine.

Comment: The materials to fix ED-E are over at the lone wolf radio location west of the road from goodsprings to primm...